# Build Web Parts on Visual Studio 2008 for SharePoint 2010

Tags: visual-studio, sharepoint, web-parts, sharepoint-2010

What do I need to install for building a Web Part for SharePoint 2010 on Visual Studio 2008? BTW: I'm using Windows 7 64-bit and Office 32-bit

Comment: Can anybody help me on this please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I *highly* recommend the [WSPBuilder 2010 Beta](http://keutmann.blogspot.com/2009/12/wspbuilder-2010-beta.html) - VS2010 is supported, but not required.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't need anything beyond what you need for SharePoint 2007 development. Just make sure you do the following:

- add assembly reference to the proper Microsoft.SharePoint.dll (i.e. version 14)
- target .NET 3.5
- target 64-bit CPU (or AnyCPU)

The CAML for the solution, feature and element manifests is the same as SharePoint 2007.